# Select MAX, but want to show the other columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Oke, I have this data:

```
INSERT INTO JobHistory(EmployeeID, EffDate, EffSeq, EmploymentStatus,
JobTitle, Salary, ActionDesc)
VALUES
(1000,'07-31-2008',1,'A','Intern',2000,'New Hire'),
(1000,'05-31-2009',1,'A','Production Technician',2000,'Title Change'),
(1000,'05-31-2009',2,'A','Production Technician',2500,'Salary Change'),
(1000,'11-01-2009',1,'A','Production Technician',3000,'Salary Change'),
(1200,'01-10-2009',1,'A','Design Engineer',5000,'New Hire'),
(1200,'05-01-2009',1,'T','Design Engineer',5000,'Termination'),
(1100,'08-01-2008',1,'A','Accounts Payable Specialist I',2500,'New Hire'),
(1100,'05-03-2009',1,'A','Accounts Payable Specialist II',2500,'Title Change'),
(1100,'05-01-2009',2,'A','Accounts Payable Specialist II',3000,'Salary Change');
```

and if I do this:

```
SELECT MAX(EffDate) as MaxDate--, EmployeeID, JobTitle
FROM JobHistory
```

you will get the MAX EffData(11-01-2009). ok. But now you will see only the column: EffData. But I also want to show the EmployeeID and JobTitle for that only returned record. But you can't do that, because you have to use then `GROUP BY`. And than you will return more records

ANd with a CTE it is also not possible.

So how to return just one record(the max of Effdata) but also shown the EmployeeID and jobtitle?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `TOP 1` with `Order by` not `Max` aggregate

```
SELECT Top 1 EffDate as MaxDate, EmployeeID, JobTitle
FROM JobHistory
Order by MaxDate desc
```

In case there is a Tie in max `EffDate` then and you want to see the Tie records then use `TOP 1 with Ties`

```
SELECT Top 1 with Ties EffDate as MaxDate, EmployeeID, JobTitle
FROM JobHistory
Order by MaxDate desc
```